# Check out latest master branch after current branch is merged into it by another user

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Let's say I have a single **Master** branch and I push some new code into the **Feature-A** branch, which is a sub-branch from **Master**:

- - Feature-A
- Master

Now I have the **Feature-A** branch checked out.

Later a different person merges **Feature-A** into **Master** and closes the **Feature-A** branch:

- Master (merged with Feature-A)
- - Feature-A
- Master

But now Sourcetree is stuck with the old **Feature-A** branch and I have to resort to using reset --hard to move to the latest **Master** commit and get rid of all **Feature-A** references.

Is there a way to make this process more streamlined? Ideally I would like a script/simple button sequence to automatically move to the latest **Master** commit,

Comment: Just to be clear, have you pulled or fetched all changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to remember here is that `Feature-A` has been merged into `Master`, but `Feature-A` itself has not been updated. Therefore `Feature-A` is still where it was - the middle commit in your second diagram.

If you do `reset --hard`, you're forcing your `Feature-A` branch to point to `Master`, but that isn't what has happened in the remote repository.

Instead you probably want to simply checkout `Master` and continue working; or perhaps create a new feature branch starting at `Master`.